# Bind значения к ресурсу приложения

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Пытался создать привязку значения к `Properties.Settings.Default.SettingsTextBrush` и `Properties.Settings.Default.SettingsContrastBrushColor`, самому не удалось, нашел примеры только к ресурсам окна, а не приложения. Как это можно сделать?

---

```
<Application 
         <!-- code -->
             xmlns:properties="graphic_panel.Properties">
    <Application.Resources>

        <Color x:Key="ContrastBrushColor">#FF74C365</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBrush" Color="{Binding SettingsTextBrush}"/>

<Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня работает так:

```
<Application x:Class="Test.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:Test..Properties"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush
            x:Key="TextBrush"
            Color="{Binding SettingsContrastBrushColor,
                            Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}}"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Не забудьте положить в settings цвет типа `System.Windows.Media.Color`, а не `System.Drawing.Color`.

Comment: У меня в приложении можно изменить цвет компонентов, и в анимации тоже привязка к этому цвету. После бинда этого цвета в ресурсы, все приложение подверглось анимации
'<SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="{StaticResource ContrastBrushColor}"/>' И текстбокс в котором менялся цвет постоянно меняет свое содержимое, при сохранении изменений конечно возникает ошибка доступа к ресурсу. Не понимаю вообще почему все начало анимироваться...

Comment: @i4el0vek: Нипанятна! Дайте код (а лучше, задайте отдельный вопрос).